# How can I center an element's side to middle of an other element?

Tags: android, layout, android-xml, android-constraintlayout

I'm using ConstraintLayout and would like to center an element's left side to the middle of an element which is above it.

```
[I'm Element 1]

        | // middle of element 1

        [Element 2 should start at middle of element 1]
```

Is this possible without writing code, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can align element 2 using constraints. To center an element you can constraint the left side to the left side of element 1 and do the same for the right side. So in xml it would be something like:

```
<Element2
    android:id="@+id/element2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/element1"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/element1" />
```

That should center it horizontally. If you also want to center it vertically simply add the top and bottom constraints.

Edit: Misunderstood the question, if you want to align the left side of an element to the center of another element you can use a `GuideLine`

Create a Guideline and position it's baseline to the baseline of Element1:

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/element1"/>
```

Then align the left side of your element2 to the GuideLine

```
<Element2
    android:id="@+id/element2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline" />
```

Comment: @ktamas No problem! :) Please accept the answer if it worked! Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, so this wasn't my question. Your answer is for centering the whole content below another one, but my question was to center the left side to the middle of another one.

Comment: @ktamas Sorry about that, misunderstood the question. I've edited my original answer.

Comment: That still doesn't work, the baseline is horizontal, so when you align anything to it, it will be aligned vertically, but my guideline needs to be aligned horizontally (to horizontal center of `element1`) and the guideline itself should be vertical.

However I tried aligning a guideline's left to `element1`'s left and guideline's right to `element1`'s right and than align `element2` to guideline but that still doesn't work.

Comment: @ktamas To make a guide vertical you need to set the height of the guide to 0dp and the width to match_parent

Comment: As the documentation says: [ling](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Guideline.html)
There are 3 ways to position Guideline, and it's not possible to align it to the center of another element.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was the following: Instead of a guideline, use a 1px * 1px `View` as a guideline, position it to the center of `element1` with `layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf` & `layout_constraintRight_toRightOf` attributes and then align `element2` to this `View` guideline:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    ...

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/element1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <View
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="1px"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="#00000000"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/element1"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/element1" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/element2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/element1" />

    ...
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```